# Is VSTS compatible with Azure GovCloud?

Tags: azure-gov

Is Microsoft Visual Studio Team Services is compatible with an instance of Azure GovCloud?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - You can use Azure Gov as a target for deployments from with in the Azure DevOps (new name for Visual Studio Team Services).  Here is an example - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-government/connect-with-azure-pipelines